# parsing dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have this input: `2020-03-11` and I want to return `03-11`, How can I do that in R?. For example, if I want to have only month, I can assign the month this way: `Month=lubridate::month(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "2020-03-11"
month <-month(x)
day <- day(x)
paste(month,"-",day)
```

and here is the result:

```
"3 - 11"
```

So, basically, I used `lubridate` to extract day and month and then used `paste` function to put those two together.

Another alternative is to use the code below (no `lubridate`):

```
format(as.Date(x), "%m-%d")
```

here is the result:

```
"03-11"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways. All are vectorized, i.e. `x` can be a vector of such strings. No packages are used.

```
x <- "2020-03-11"  # input

substring(x, 6)

sub("\\d+-", "", x)

trimws(trimws(x, "left", "\\d"), "left", "-")

format(as.Date(x), "%m-%d")
```

A different approach is to create an S3 subclass of `Date` that represents a Date but displays just the month and day storing the full date so that it is recoverable.  `as.md` constructs an object of this new class, `as.Date.md` converts it back to `Date` class and `format.md` formats it.  If we print such as object it will look for `print.md` but we have not defined it so it will use `print.Date`, the print method of the super class of `md`, and that method calls `format` invoking `format.md`.

```
as.md <- function(x, ...) structure(as.Date(x), class = c("md", "Date"))
as.Date.md <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = "Date")
format.md <- function(x, format = "%m-%d", ...) format(as.Date(x), format = format, ...)

y <- as.md(x)

y
## [1] "03-11"

as.Date(y)  # recover the full date
##[1] "2020-03-11"

data.frame(x, y)
##            x     y
## 1 2020-03-11 03-11
```